# Jenkinsfile Checkout with GIT_BRANCH

Tags: linux, git, jenkins-pipeline

I want to checkout a specific branch with the git plugin. I cannot get the environment variable GIT_BRANCH to work, below is a snippet;

```
 stage('Checkout') {
   steps {
    sh 'mkdir authentication'
    dir('authentication') {
     checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
      branches: [
       [name: 'env.GIT_BRANCH/${branchToBuild}']
      ],
```

The `branchToBuild` is my parameter variable. All I want to do is select the branch from 'Build with Parameters'. Is this possible?

I have managed to do it with;

```
stage('Checkout') {
   steps {
    sh 'mkdir authentication'
    dir('authentication') {
     checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
      branches: [
       [name: 'refs/remotes/${branchToBuild}']
      ],
```

Is there a way without hardcoding `refs/remotes`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using double quotes for strings where you want to use variables mixed with text. Also make sure to enclose GIT_BRANCH in ${} for it to be recognised as a Groovy expression.

Try:

```
[name: "${env.GIT_BRANCH}/${branchToBuild}"]
```

Why do you need the GIT_BRANCH variable? Would not branchToBuild be enough?

Answer (score 0):

Below code may help to you

```
stage('checkout'){
  git branch: '${branchToBuild}', url: 'GITURL'
}
```